# Drag only the horizontal scrollbar amount

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I am trying to use jQuery Ui to drag an overflowing child div, this div does drag but further than I like. I only want it to drag the scroll-able amount.

Hopefully this codepen will show you want I mean -

http://codepen.io/seanjacob/pen/RKKEyO

```
$(".box").draggable({axis: "x"});
```

All widths will be responsive. It doesn't have to be a jQuery Ui solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what I was looking for -

http://qnimate.com/javascript-scroll-by-dragging/

github: https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll

It just drags the scrollbar, nothing more or less and is responsive.